# Relative layout : Two text view auto re-size

Tags: android, android-layout

How to set up a layout which updates UI based on available space.For example, I have two TextView in a relative layout. First, one is used to display the description which may be varies depending on the content.Second, is used to display the date of that content.

Currently, I am displaying date TextView below the description TextView.But, I need to change the date TextView position based on the description Textview length.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [Google's FlexboxLayout library](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:flexWrap="wrap"
    app:justifyContent="flex_end"
    app:alignItems="flex_start"
    app:alignContent="flex_start">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello world!"
        app:layout_flexGrow="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Oct 26, 2017 at 1:36 AM"/>

</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what are you looking for?

[image]

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context="test.example.solutions.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="test" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Oct 26, 2017 at 4:44PM" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is this an answer?